# Deferred action failure handling

Tags: action

Is there some kind of trigger that notifies if a deferred action failed to execute; being the failure either by lack of resources for running the action in the paying account, or a non satisfied assertion in the code or simply a bug on it?

Is there something like an automated retry ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/36a26bbe874f7432b6c59757aa37b9ab28963dba/libraries/chain/controller.cpp#L386

an `onerror` action will be dispatched to the sending contract with the transaction data as parameter